# npm audit fix error - "ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE npm ERR! The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules

We are updating from React 16 to React 18.2, and we are updating several other packages in our project as well to avoid conflicts. Following these updates, we are running into an odd issue:

- delete `node_modules`
- run `npm install`
- run `npm audit fix` to resolve issues

And we receive the following error:
[image]

After running `npm audit fix` and receiving this error, it leads to something else problematic where we can no longer uninstall any packages (this 2nd issue does not occur if we never run `npm audit fix` after the `npm install`):

[image]

In our `node_modules` folder, we already have the `.acorns-globals-b12RT7fM` file for which the error message is telling us that we need to rename `acorns-globals` to:

[image]

When we delete `node_modules` and start this process from the start, we run into the same issue each time. How can we initially resolve the issue with `npm audit fix` that then causes these other issues w/ uninstalling packages?

Our **package.json** file:

```
{
    "name": "the-cbbap-client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
        "@sentry/react": "^7.14.0",
        "@sentry/tracing": "^5.24.2",
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.2.2",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.12.1",
        "@tidyjs/tidy": "^2.0.8",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "d3-array": "^3.1.6",
        "d3-axis": "^3.0.0",
        "d3-collection": "^1.0.7",
        "d3-drag": "^3.0.0",
        "d3-ease": "^3.0.1",
        "d3-force": "^3.0.0",
        "d3-format": "^3.1.0",
        "d3-hexbin": "^0.2.2",
        "d3-hierarchy": "^3.1.2",
        "d3-interpolate": "^3.0.1",
        "d3-regression": "^1.3.10",
        "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
        "d3-selection": "^3.0.0",
        "d3-shape": "^3.1.0",
        "d3-timer": "^3.0.1",
        "d3-transition": "^3.0.1",
        "jquery": "^3.5.0",
        "match-sorter": "^4.1.0",
        "mathjs": "^9.3.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "rc-input-number": "^6.2.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
        "react-confetti": "^6.0.0",
        "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-ga": "^3.2.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
        "react-mailchimp-subscribe": "^2.1.0",
        "react-pay-icons": "^3.0.0",
        "react-player": "^1.15.3",
        "react-query": "^3.5.11",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
        "react-select": "^5.4.0",
        "react-spinners": "^0.12.0",
        "react-switch": "^7.0.0",
        "react-table": "^7.8.0",
        "react-table-sticky": "^1.1.2",
        "react-twitter-embed": "^4.0.4",
        "sass": "^1.54.5",
        "use-deep-compare-effect": "^1.3.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.6.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build-css": "sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/",
        "watch-css": "npm run build-css && sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/ --watch",
        "start-js": "react-scripts start",
        "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
        "build": "react-scripts build --stats",
        "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer build/bundle-stats.json",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your package.json file?

Comment: Yes I have added it to the posting

Comment: I suppose that the first issue was resolved? It seems to be related with wrong way of import package in one of your files.